# missing x-userinfo header when using keycloack and kong-oicd

Tags: docker, keycloak, openid, kong

am trying to use `kong oicd` with `keycloak 19.0.3` to secure my app and that my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM kong/kong:2.7.0

ENV OIDC_PLUGIN_VERSION=1.2.3-2
ENV GIT_VERSION=2.24.4-r0
ENV UNZIP_VERSION=6.0-r7
ENV LUAROCKS_VERSION=2.4.4-r1


USER root
RUN apk update && apk add git unzip luarocks
RUN luarocks install kong-oidc

RUN git clone --branch v1.2.3-2 https://github.com/revomatico/kong-oidc.git
WORKDIR /kong-oidc
RUN luarocks make

RUN luarocks pack kong-oidc ${OIDC_PLUGIN_VERSION} \
     && luarocks install kong-oidc-${OIDC_PLUGIN_VERSION}.all.rock

WORKDIR /
RUN git clone --branch 20200505-access-token-processing https://github.com/BGaunitz/kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak.git
WORKDIR /kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak
RUN luarocks make

RUN luarocks pack kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak ${JWT_PLUGIN_VERSION} \
     && luarocks install kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak-${JWT_PLUGIN_VERSION}.all.rock

USER kong
```

i did configure by passing the `client id` and `client secret` and the `descovery endpoint`

[image]
[image]

when i visit the configured route in kong i get redirected to keycloak to authenticate and after success auth i get redirected back to my app but when i check the headers i find no `x-userUnfo` and i find only `session cookie` am i missing something ?
[image]

am using nginx as an app to test in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont't see those request headers in the request from your browser to Kong but in the upstream request from Kong to your service. The OIDC plugin will inject them.

One note about the jwt-keycloak plugin: you have to change its prority, e.g. to

```
ENV JWT_KEYCLOAK_PRIORITY="900"
```

Otherwise it will be executed before the OIDC plugin but you want to have it afterwards.

Comment: i did figure that out but am thankful for your answer and i want to ask about the logout using the oicd now i did set logout post redirect uri to to the url provided by keycloak when i visit /logout its dose redirect me to logout page with button to logout when i press the button i get logged out but it dosent rdirect me back to the login page it just stay on the logout page and display the text "you are logged out" and am really wondering how i redirect back to the login page after loggin out

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/revomatico/kong-oidc for oidc and https://github.com/hanfi/kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak for jwt.
I enabled 2 plugin with scope required is user.
When i get access token and connect to service with:

```
#!/bin/bash

auth_url='http://localhost:8080/'
realm_name='kong'
client_id='kong_client'
client_secret='CEkLLq8qhWvHhccWxk5LSirfWM0hkcDm'
username='user1'
password='123abc'
url='http://localhost:8000/httpbin2'
token=$(curl -X POST \
    "${auth_url}/realms/${realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "client_id=${client_id}" \
    -d "client_secret=${client_secret}" \
    -d "username=${username}" \
    -d "password=${password}" \
    -d "grant_type=password" | jq -r '.access_token')
```

The connection successed authen with scope 'user'.
But when I visit the configured route in kong with browser i get redirected to keycloak to authenticate and after success auth i get this error:

> {"message":"Unauthorized"}

. Is this error by cookie?